# How can I access a specific value of a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to access a specific value in a multidimensional array, but I am getting an undefined index error.

**Here is my code :**

```
     $hasil_ringkasan=array();
     foreach ($hasil_kelas as $key => $value) {
            $mayoritas = array_count_values($value);
            if($mayoritas['ringkasan']>1){
                array_push($hasil_ringkasan,$key);
            }

     }
```

**Here is the output of** `$hasil_kelas :`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ringkasan
            [1] => ringkasan
            [2] => bukan
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ringkasan
            [1] => ringkasan
            [2] => ringkasan
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ringkasan
            [1] => ringkasan
            [2] => ringkasan
        )

)
```

But why when I run my first code is there an error "`Message:  Undefined index: ringkasan`" even though the conditional is successfully executed?

**My expected output like this :**

```
Array(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 9
    [6] => 11
    [7] => 14
    [8] => 16
    [9] => 19
    [10] => 20
 )
```

Comment: there is no key ringkasan so it's undefined

Comment: but when i print_r `$mayoritas = array_count_values($value);` the key is ringkasan @JYoThI

Comment: Describe the question more clearly so that readers can contribute....

Comment: can you show your expected output

Comment: Maybe somewhere in your array, you have an element without any ringkasan.

Comment: @JYoThI , my expected output like in above, i've edited my question

Comment: try my below answer @Rachmad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any array is not have element  `ringkasan` means it will through `undefined` `errro` so use `isset` to check

Example :

```
     `[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => bukan
        [1] => bukan
        [2] => bukan
    )`
```

In above example you will get

```
array(['bukan']=>3);  //so here is no ringkasan  key .
```

So use `isset` to check variable exists or not and then compare

```
if(isset($mayoritas['ringkasan']) && $mayoritas['ringkasan']>1)
{
    array_push($hasil_ringkasan,$key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JYoThl, I've tried your code and success, but I just want it to push the `$key` not `$value`, so I just change it. Thank..for help me.. :)

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @Rachmad

Answer (score 1):

Test if `ringkasan` is present

```
 $hasil_ringkasan=array();
 foreach ($hasil_kelas as $key => $value) {
        $mayoritas = array_count_values($value);
        if(isset($mayoritas['ringkasan']) && $mayoritas['ringkasan']>1){
            array_push($hasil_ringkasan,$key);
        }

 }
```